# I am trying to create new operations for my calculator but only the sum function works, the other operations are displayed as 'NaN' or are incorrect

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and programming in general. I've taken a challenge of building a calculator usign HTML/CSS and JavaScript, I've already managed to add the sum function so the two numbers split by '+' are summed and the result shows up in the same text input. But I can't seem to get it working for the other operations. For example, whenever I try to subtract, let's say 5-3, the result is -8...

Also, if I make a different operation first, the other operations I try to make after will display 'NaN' in the text input. For example, if I operate a sum first and then try to operate a subtraction, the result will not be "-8", it will display 'NaN' instead, and vice versa...

```js
var equals = document.querySelector('#equals');
// The textfield element
var visor = document.getElementById("visor");
// The reset button
var resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
// Get all the buttons to an Array
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("key");
// Get all operators button
var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
var subtract = document.getElementById("subtract");
var multiply = document.getElementById("multiply");
var divide = document.getElementById("divide");

function numbersAndOperators() {

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, (button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      visor.value += button.innerText
    })
  })

  // Add click event listener to reset button
  resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    visor.value = null
  })
}

plus.addEventListener('click', function() {
  equals.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var valAdd = visor.value.split('+');
    visor.value = valAdd.reduce((a, c) => a + Number(c), 0);
  });
});

subtract.addEventListener('click', function() {
  equals.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var valSub = visor.value.split('-');
    visor.value = valSub.reduce((a, c) => a - Number(c), 0);
  });
});

multiply.addEventListener('click', function() {
  equals.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var valMul = visor.value.split('*');
    visor.value = valMul.reduce((a, c) => a * Number(c), 0);
  });
});

divide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  equals.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var valDiv = visor.value.split('/');
    visor.value = valDiv.reduce((a, c) => a / Number(c), 0);
  });
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", numbersAndOperators);
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="title-theme">
    <div>
      <h1>Calc</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="theme">
      <p>Theme</p><input type="range" min="0" max="2" id="range"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="visor">
    <div><input type="text" id="visor"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key key_7">7</button><button class="key key_8">8</button><button class="key key_9">9</button><button class="key_DEL" id="del">DEL</button>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key key_4">4</button><button class="key key_5">5</button><button class="key key_6">6</button><button class="key key_+" id="plus">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key key_1">1</button><button class="key key_2">2</button><button class="key key_3">3</button><button class="key key_-" id="subtract">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key key_period">.</button><button class="key key_0">0</button><button class="key key_/" id="divide">/</button><button class="key key_x" id="multiply">*</button>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key_reset" id="reset">RESET</button><button class="key_=" id="equals">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Previously, the JS for the equals button was like that:

```
equals.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (visor.value.split('+')){
        visor.value = visor.value.split('+').reduce((a,c) => a + Number(c), 0);
    }
    if (visor.value.split('-')){
        visor.value = visor.value.split('-').reduce((a,c) => a - Number(c), 0);
    }
    if (visor.value.split('*')){
      visor.value = visor.value.split('*').reduce((a,c) => a * Number(c), 0);
    }
    if (visor.value.split('/')){
      visor.value = visor.value.split('/').reduce((a,c) => a / Number(c), 0);
    }
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", numbersAndOperators);
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. "Not working" doesn't do it. Note that only one question should be asked per post.

Comment: You normally shouldn't call `addEventListener()` inside another event listener. Each time you click on an operation button you add another listener to the equals button. Then when you click on equals, it will run all of those listeners.

Comment: The name of the method should make this clear: it *adds* a listener, it doesn't *replace* the listener. So the previous listener doesn't go away.

Comment: @Barmar before writing this code, I wrote a previous one using conditions, but I reached the same results... I'll edit this post so I can show you.

Comment: @Barmar, there I sent the code... Can you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way you're using `reduce()`. You're starting with an initial value `0`, then using `reduce()` to subtract each number from it. So `5-3` is being treated as `0-5-3`.

After splitting, you should use the first value as the initial value, then subtract the rest. So change

```
visor.value = valSub.reduce((a, c) => a - Number(c), 0);
```

to

```
visor.value = valSub.slice(1).reduce(a, c) => c - Number(c), Number(valSub[0]));
```

Comment: Ok, that did seem to work with my subtraction and other operations problem! Thank you very much, but the NaN problem persists... It only operates the last line of code... I used the conditionals and left the division operation for last, so now I'm unable to make the other operations... What to do?

Comment: Alright, I managed to solve the issue with a friend. All I had to do was change the parameters from Number() to parseFloat(), but I had to do it on both parameters, something like that: parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(c). Yet, thank you very much for your time!

Comment: `Number()` and `parseFloat()` should both work. `a` is already a number, so you shouldn't need `parseFloat(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I managed to solve the issue with a friend based on @Barmar's contribution. All I had to do was change the parameters from Number() to parseFloat(), but I had to do it on both parameters.

```
<!--begin snippet-->
<body>
  <div class="title-theme">
    <div><h1>Calc</h1></div>
    <div class="theme"><p>Theme</p><input type="range" min="0" max="2" id="range"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="visor">
    <div><input type="text" id="visor"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key key_7">7</button><button class="key key_8">8</button><button class="key key_9">9</button><button class="key_DEL" id="del" >DEL</button>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key key_4">4</button><button class="key key_5">5</button><button class="key key_6">6</button><button class="key key_+" id="plus">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key key_1">1</button><button class="key key_2">2</button><button class="key key_3">3</button><button  class="key key_-" id="subtract">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key key_period">.</button><button  class="key key_0">0</button><button class="key key_/" id="divide">/</button><button class="key key_x" id="multiply">*</button>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <button class="key_reset" id="reset">RESET</button><button class="key_=" id="equals">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
var equals = document.querySelector('#equals');
var visor = document.getElementById("visor");
var resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("key");
var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
var subtract = document.getElementById("subtract");
var multiply = document.getElementById("multiply");
var divide = document.getElementById("divide");

function numbersAndOperators() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call (buttons, (button) => {
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        visor.value += button.innerText
      })
    })
    resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      visor.value = null
    })
}

equals.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (visor.value.split('-')){
    visor.value = visor.value.split('-').slice(1).reduce((a, c) => parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(c), (visor.value.split('-')[0]));
  }
  if (visor.value.split('+')){
    visor.value = visor.value.split('+').slice(1).reduce((a, c) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(c), (visor.value.split('+')[0]));
  }
  if (visor.value.split('*')){
    visor.value = visor.value.split('*').slice(1).reduce((a, c) => parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(c), (visor.value.split('*')[0]));
  }
  if (visor.value.split('/')){
    visor.value = visor.value.split('/').slice(1).reduce((a, c) => parseFloat(a) / parseFloat(c), (visor.value.split('/')[0]));
  }
})

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", numbersAndOperators);
</script>
<!--end snippet-->
```